# Android: why doesn't AlarmManager work?

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, alarmmanager

I have the following code. which is supposed to send a message in logcat at an interval but is not working. There are a lot of similar posts on stackoverflow but I am not able to figure out the problem. Is there a brainiac somewhere that can help me?

```
<receiver android:name="BoopoohooAlarmReceiver"></receiver>

public void startAlarmManager(long interval){
    Context context = getApplicationContext();
    Intent intent = new Intent(context, BoopoohooAlarmReceiver.class);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, intent, 0);
    AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager)context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    calendar.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());
    calendar.add(Calendar.SECOND, 10);
    Log.i(DEBUG, "hollaa");
    alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(), interval, pendingIntent);
}

public class BoopoohooAlarmReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    private final String DEBUG = "BoopoohooAlarmReceiver"; 
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Log.i(DEBUG, "onReceive");
    }
}
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try to add the "." (point) in front of receiver name in the android manifest file declaration.

```
<receiver android:name=".BoopoohooAlarmReceiver"></receiver>
```

[This](http://androidresearch.wordpress.com/2012/07/02/scheduling-an-application-to-start-later/) may help too.

Answer (score 0):

Refer this links [Alarm Manager 1](http://smartandroidians.blogspot.in/2010/04/alarmmanager-and-notification-in.html) , [Alarm Manager 2](http://android-er.blogspot.in/2010/10/simple-example-of-alarm-service-using.html) , [Alarm Manager 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4459058/alarm-manager-example)it will be helpful